# Using xlsx for netmiko session

Tags: python, networking, netmiko

I want to use both user input (for username/pw) and an excel file (for ip/device_type) for a netmiko connecthandler session for every device in the excel file reusing the account info provided. Right now the user input is static but I will get to that later. How do I build the connecthandler?

from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas as pd

accountinfo = {
'username': 'admin',
'password': 'password',
'secret': 'cisco',
}

devices = pd.read_excel('Hosts.xlsx', usecols='b,e')

print (devices)

IP              Device Type

0  192.168.0.118   cisco_ios

Comment: You could improve readability to get better feedback by using code formatting to show the difference between code and text of your question, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387765/what-is-the-preferred-method-for-formatting-code

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you can iterate over the rows of the Excel file and use the information from each row to establish a Netmiko session with the corresponding device.
Example of how you can build the ConnectHandler

```py
import pandas as pd
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

# Read data from the Excel file
accountinfo = {"username": "admin", "password": "password", "secret": "cisco"}
devices = pd.read_excel("Hosts.xlsx")
print(devices)
#                IP Device Type
# 0  192.168.0.118    cisco_ios

# Iterate over the devices in the DataFrame and establish SSH connections
for index, row in devices.iterrows():
    device = {"ip": row["IP"], "device_type": row["Device Type"]}
    device.update(accountinfo)
    ssh = ConnectHandler(**device)
    try:
        output = ssh.send_command("show version")
        print(device["ip"])
        print(output)
        # 192.168.0.118
        # Cisco IOS Software, C2960X Software (C2960X-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)E10, ...
        ssh.disconnect()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"{type(ex).__name__}: {ex}")
```